# 404 thrown when trying to load CSS

Tags: symfony

So I want to load CSS on my twig with the following line of code:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

The assets folder is on the root of my project folder. However, a 404 was being thrown when the browser load the asset.

This is my Nginx Config:

```
server {
    server_name yventee-backoffice.local;
    root /var/www/html/backoffice/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have the `symfony/asset` component, you can take a look at the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html

Comment: yep i have symfony/asset installed.

Comment: the assets must be in the **/public/** directory so that the web app will be able to access them. Also i would like to suggest you to use the new Webpack encore to manage your assets http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Comment: still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want to engage with Webpack encore yet.

Comment: what is the physical path of the asset you try to load? **/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css** ?

Comment: yep just moved it to public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: and I confirmed that the file actually exist.

Comment: in the line you posted there is a typo, **boostrap** instead of **bootstrap** make sure you do not have the same typo in your folder

Comment: I edited the comment, it should be bootstrap still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163544/discussion-between-knetsi-and-iamjc015).